# Web Audio API in Aptana Studio 3 or Komodo

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, aptana, komodo

Is there a way to get a autocomplete/code assist for the [Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) with Aptana Studio 3 or Komodo, or maybe a way to build my own code assist with the API?

Cheers,

Rainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Komodo autocomplete support can be extended using [JSDoc](http://community.activestate.com/many-ways-extending-komodo) [annotations](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/getting-more-your-php-and-javascript-code) or [code intelligence](http://community.activestate.com/forum/code-intelligence-putting-it-all-together) files, following the Komodo source for [jQuery](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/master/src/codeintel/support/gencix/javascript/jquery/jquery_xmlAPI_to_cix.py)